# Capture property names

Tags: python, regex

I'm scanning a ".twig" (PHP template) file and trying to capture the property names of an object.

The twig file contains lines (strings) like these:

```
{{ product.id }}
{{ product.parentProductId }}
{{ product.countdown.startDate | date('Y/m/d H:i:s') }}
{{ product.countdown.endDate | date('Y/m/d H:i:s') }}
{{ product.countdown.expireDate | date('Y/m/d H:i:s') }}
{{ product.primaryImage.originalUrl }}
{{ product.image(1).originalUrl }}
{{ product.image(1).thumbUrl }}
{{ product.priceWithTax(preferences.default_currency) | money }}
```

The things I want to capture are:

```
.id
.parentProductId
.countdown
.startDate
.endDate
.expireDate
.primaryImage
.originalUrl
.image(1)
.originalUrl
.thumbUrl
.priceWithTax(preferences.default_currency)
```

Basically, I'm trying to figure out the properties of the `product` object. I have the following pattern, but it doesn't capture chained properties. For example,

`"{{.+?product(\.[a-zA-Z]+(?:\(.+?\)){,1})++.+?}}"` captures only `.startDate`, but it should capture both `.countdown` and `.startDate` seperately. Is this not possible, or am I missing something?

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2lVAcg/2)

I could capture (`"{{.+?product((?:\.[a-zA-Z]+(?:\(.+?\)){,1})+).+?}}"`) it as a whole (`.countdown.startDate`) and later check/split it, but this sounds troublesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle it with a single regex, you might want to use the PyPi `regex` module:

```
import regex

s = """{{ product.id }}
{{ product.parentProductId }}
{{ product.countdown.startDate | date('Y/m/d H:i:s') }}
{{ product.primaryImage.originalUrl }}
{{ product.image(1).originalUrl }}
{{ product.priceWithTax(preferences.default_currency) | money }}"""

rx = r'{{[^{}]*product(\.[a-zA-Z]+(?:\([^()]+\))?)*[^{}]*}}'

l = [m.captures(1) for m in regex.finditer(rx, s)]

print([item for sublist in l for item in sublist])
# => ['.id', '.parentProductId', '.countdown', '.startDate', '.primaryImage', '.originalUrl', '.image(1)', '.originalUrl', '.priceWithTax(preferences.default_currency)']
```

See the [Python demo](http://rextester.com/ODUPD48571)

The `{{[^{}]*product(\.[a-zA-Z]+(?:\([^()]+\))?)*[^{}]*}}` regex will match

- `{{` - `{{` substring
- `[^{}]*` - 0+ chars other than `{` and `}`
- `product` - the substring `product`
- `(\.[a-zA-Z]+(?:\([^()]+\))?)*` - Capturing group 1: zero or more sequences of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `[a-zA-Z]+` - 1+ ASCII letters
  - `(?:\([^()]+\))?` - an optional sequence of `(`, 1+ chars other than `(` and `)` and then `)`
- `[^{}]*` - 0+ chars other than `{` and `}`
- `}}`  - a `}}` substring.

If you are only limited to `re`, you will need to capture all the properties into 1 capturing group (wrap this `(\.[a-zA-Z]+(?:\([^()]+\))?)*` with `(...)`) and then run a regex based post-process to split by `.` not inside parentheses:

```
import re
rx = r'{{[^{}]*product((?:\.[a-zA-Z]+(?:\([^()]+\))?)*)[^{}]*}}'
l = re.findall(rx, s)
res = []
for m in l:
     res.extend([".{}".format(n) for n in filter(None, re.split(r'\.(?![^()]*\))', m))])
print(res)
# => ['.id', '.parentProductId', '.countdown', '.startDate', '.primaryImage', '.originalUrl', '.image(1)', '.originalUrl', '.priceWithTax(preferences.default_currency)']
```

See [this Python demo](http://rextester.com/FZKX9931)

Answer (score 0):

try this one, captures all in your requirement

```
^{{ product(\..*?[(][^\d\/]+[)]).*?}}|^{{ product(\..*?)(\..*?)?(?= )
```

[demo and explanation at regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/nCEIPY/1)

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to stick to `re` (instead of `regex`, as suggested by Victor) and this is what I ended up with:

```
import re, json

file = open("test.twig", "r", encoding="utf-8")
content = file.read()
file.close()

patterns = {
    "template"  : r"{{[^{}]*product((?:\.[a-zA-Z]+(?:\([^()]+\))?)*)[^{}]*}}",
    "prop"      : r"^[^\.]+$",                  # .id
    "subprop"   : r"^[^\.()]+(\.[^\.]+)+$",     # .countdown.startDate
    "itemprop"  : r"^[^\.]+\(\d+\)\.[^\.]+$",   # .image(1).originalUrl
    "method"    : r"^[^\.]+\(.+\)$",            # .priceWithTax(preferences.default_currency)
}

temp_re = re.compile(patterns["template"])
matches = temp_re.findall(content)

product = {}

for match in matches:
    match = match[1:]
    if re.match(patterns["prop"], match):
        product[match] = match
    elif re.match(patterns["subprop"], match):
        match = match.split(".")
        if match[0] not in product:
            product[match[0]] = []
        if match[1] not in product[match[0]]:
            product[match[0]].append(match[1])
    elif re.match(patterns["itemprop"], match):
        match = match.split(".")
        array = re.sub("\(\d+\)", "(i)", match[0])
        if array not in product:
            product[array] = []
        if match[1] not in product[array]:
            product[array].append(match[1])
    elif re.match(patterns["method"], match):
        product[match] = match

props = json.dumps(product, indent=4)

print(props)
```

Example output:

```
{
    "id": "id",
    "parentProductId": "parentProductId",
    "countdown": [
        "startDate",
        "endDate",
        "expireDate"
    ],
    "primaryImage": [
        "originalUrl"
    ],
    "image(i)": [
        "originalUrl",
        "thumbUrl"
    ],
    "priceWithTax(preferences.default_currency)": "priceWithTax(preferences.default_currency)"
}
```